# Building a WAN emulator

Tags: networking

I'd like to use the Raspberry Pi 2 as a WAN emulator, i.e.

- It would have 2 network adapters (1 built-in, 1 USB)
- It acts as a "man in the middle" between 2 hosts
- It delays packets, randomizes the order of packets, drops packets, modifies packets, ...

I know [WANEM](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/), but it does not seem that would work with a Raspberry Pi. At least I don't know how to boot from an ISO. I also know [Clumsy](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/), but that's for Windows only.

How would I build above functionality with the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [fairly lengthy tutorial](https://www.disk91.com/2013/technology/systems/raspberry-pi-wan-emulation/) on [disk91.com](https://www.disk91.com) that looks promising. It's a little dated and based on Wheezy rather than Jessie, but I think it should at least provide some pointers.

A USB ethernet dongle was connected to an original model B Pi. The network configuration was then changed to allow traffic to flow between the built in network adapter and the dongle. They used [dnsmasq](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq) to allow the Pi to act as a DNS server to a device on the local network.

To create given conditions on the network they used [tc](https://wiki.debian.org/TrafficControl). They chose to manipulate connection bandwidth and latency, but from the look of the man page you can play with it to create a wide range of disturbances. To adjust the parameters they built a simple locally hosted web page which passed form inputs to a CGI script.

At the time of writing the tutorial page includes a [downloadable script](https://cdn.disk91.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/PIWan.tar) which should automagically set up their limited bandwidth/latency scenario.

Comment: I had to change a few things (like directories for lighttpd, they seem to be in /var/www/html nowadays), but otherwise excellent and very easy to follow. I also can't fully recommend the script. It needs eth0 to be the WAN interface, which in my setup isn't the case and the script does not allow to configure it.